# Can't install GRUB, no matter what

Tags: linux-mint, windows, grub2, dual-boot

My PC has Windows 7 and Mint 16 (Cinnamon). After installing Mint, GRUB stopped working, and I got a GRUB Rescue console instead of the GRUB menu. Being in a hurry, I launched the Windows installation disk and executed a series of `bootexec` commands in order to restore at least it.

Later on, I found that I could boot my Mint installation if, with the Mint Live CD in the drive, I switched to the GRUB console from the disk boot menu. After that, I typed the following:

```
set root=(hd1,msdos6)
set prefix=/boot/grub
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda6 ro
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

With Mint up and running, I ran [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/), and got the following:

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Linux Mint 16 Petra
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows XP: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:
```

(This file actually have a lot more content, but I believe that the following isn't relevant to the problem.)

And this grab my attention:

```
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
```

So I should just `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and everything would be fine right?

Well, nope. `grub-install` complains nothing, and after that running Boot Info Script gives me the exact same output. If I restart, Windows loads up without any sign of the GRUB menu.

So, what am I missing here?

Comment: After installing a new OS you should always do `update-grub` to update the GRUB record (If using GRUB). Try doing that, or download and install boot-repair (from Linux) and run that, it should restore boot records as well

Comment: @NoTime `boot-repair` did the trick. Thank you! Can you write a proper answer, in order for me to upvote you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either from your working OS, or a Live session you can install and run boot-repair for the most current version of Mint the terminal commands would be:

*Note below is from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), but will work since Mint uses same repos as Ubuntu.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Explanation of commands:

1. Add repository for boot-repair
2. Add to boot-repair to source list
3. Update changes to apt-get (repository and source)
4. Install boot-repair and run

After installing a new OS you should always do update-grub as well, to update the GRUB record/menu (If you are using GRUB).